# LIKE query using multiple keywords from search field using PDO prepared statement

Tags: php, pdo, sql-like

Site users use a search form to query a database of products. The keywords entered search the titles for the products in the database.

```
    public function startSearch($keywords){
        $keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $keywords);
        $totalKeywords = count($keywords);

        foreach($keywords as $key => $keyword){
            $search .= '%'.$keyword.'%';
            if($key != ($totalKeywords)-1){
                $search .= ' AND itemTitle LIKE ';
            }
        }
$sql=$this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM prodsTable WHERE itemTitle LIKE ?");
$sql->bindParam(1, $search);        
$sql->execute ();
$sql->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The search works if a user enters a single keyword, but if multiple keywords are used the query does not execute.

if:
$keywords = 'apple ipod';
$search = '%apple% AND itemTitle LIKE %ipod%';

So the prepared statement should look like this:

"SELECT * FROM prodsTable WHERE itemTitle LIKE %apple% AND itemTitle LIKE %ipod%"

No results return when two products should return having both "apple" and "ipod" in their titles.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM prodsTable WHERE itemTitle LIKE '%apple%' AND itemTitle LIKE '%ipod%'"`. Is your like pattern quoted?

Comment: in the foreach statement it is '%'.$keyword.'%' which returns the prepared statement of:
SELECT * FROM prodsTable WHERE itemTitle LIKE %apple%

That works. However, when adding a second or third keyword where the $search variable becomes:

'%'.$keyword.'%' AND itemTitle LIKE --> giving the prepared statement of:

SELECT * FROM prodsTable WHERE itemTitle LIKE %apple% AND itemTitle LIKE %ipod%

Doesn't work. Adding more than one keyword isn't providing results.

I've tried it as:  itemTitle LIKE '%aple%' but that doesn't work either. My original prepared without the quotes works.

Comment: `bindParam` will add quotes if needed, so its ok

Comment: Once keyword search works. More than one doesn't. This is the exact statement that is executed, but no results.

SELECT * FROM prodsTable WHERE itemTitle LIKE %apple% AND itemTitle LIKE %ipod%

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prepared statements protect you from sql injection, so sql code in the parameters will not be interpreted.  You will have to build a sql query with the correct number of  `AND itemTitle LIKE ?` before calling prepare().

```
  $keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $keywords);
  $totalKeywords = count($keywords);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM prodsTable WHERE itemTitle LIKE ?";

  for($i=1 ; $i < $totalKeywords; $i++){
    $query .= " AND itemTitle LIKE ? ";
  }

  $sql=$this->db->prepare($query);
  foreach($keywords as $key => $keyword){
    $sql->bindValue($key+1, '%'.$keyword.'%');
  }
  $sql->execute ();
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to make the following changes since it wouldn't let me pass by reference.

  foreach($keywords as $key => $keyword){
   $search = '%'.$keyword.'%';
   $sql->bindParam($key+1, $search);
  }

Very thankful for your help and I appreciate your explanation too.

Comment: This answer deserves more credit... Saved my life! :)