# Prepared Statements not returning the required multiple results

Tags: php, mysqli

I have made this function after getting some help from [How to perform a LIKE query using multiple keywords from search field using mysqli prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51088080/how-to-perform-a-like-query-using-multiple-keywords-from-search-field-using-mysq) , but made some changes as I have only one search parameter.

```
function searchResult($con, $search) {
   $keywords = explode(" ", $search);
   $total_keywords = count($keywords);
   $myquery = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')";
      for ($i=1 ; $i < $total_keywords; $i++) {
          $myquery .= " OR name LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')";
      }
   $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
   //check if the statement is not prepared
   if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $myquery)) {
       header("location: search.php?errorid=stmt_failed");
       exit();
   }
   $typeparam = '';
   foreach ($keywords as $key => $value) {
       $typeparam .= 's';
   }
   $bind_param = array();
   $bind_param[] =& $typeparam;
   foreach ($keywords as $key => $value) {
       $bind_param[]=&$keywords[$key];
   }
   call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_param'), $bind_param);
   mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
   $matches = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
   if ($searches = mysqli_fetch_assoc($matches)) {
       return $searches;
   } else {
       $result = false;
       return $result;
   }
   mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

Now, I have a table named **products** and in that table I have:

> Nikon Paint bucket

> Bricks

> Asian Paint 2 liter Blue finish

> PVC pipe

When I search only bricks, it return **Bricks**, similarly all the other products are returned. However, by searching **bricks paint** it only returns **Nikon Paint bucket**, but it should return Bricks as well as both the **Paint** results in the table. So, there are two issues, one is that it does not take multiple keywords into account. The other issue is that, it does not return two results having same keyword.

Also, Prepared statements is the best way to prevent SQL injection, but is it wise to use it in search bar as `mysqli_real_escape_string()` seems inefficient. Is there any other way to make a safe search bar?

Comment: Why aren't you using PDO?

Comment: If I were you, I would completely forget about the existence of `mysqli_real_escape_string`. Don't go that route. Just use prepared statements all the time.

Comment: I have gotten your point about escaping. Also, I am not as much familiar with PDO but looks like PDO is quite reliable and much more giving. so, PDO is the way forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function returns only one row from the result set. Calling `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` produces only a single row.

If you want to fetch all rows from the result set, you should call `mysqli_fetch_all()`. I have cleaned up the implementation and used `mysqli_fetch_all()` that will give you an array of rows.

```
function searchResult(mysqli $con, string $search): array
{
    $keywords = explode(" ", $search);
    $total_keywords = count($keywords);
    $myquery = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')";
    for ($i = 1; $i < $total_keywords; $i++) {
        $myquery .= " OR name LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')";
    }
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $myquery);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, str_repeat('s', $total_keywords), ...$keywords);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $matches = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

    return mysqli_fetch_all($matches, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

Don't forget to enable [mysqli error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439).

However, I would strongly recommend to use PDO if you can. PDO is much easier to use. Consider the same functionality using PDO:

```
function searchResult(PDO $con, string $search): array
{
    $keywords = explode(" ", $search);
    $total_keywords = count($keywords);
    $myquery = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')";
    for ($i = 1; $i < $total_keywords; $i++) {
        $myquery .= " OR name LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')";
    }
    $stmt = $con->prepare($myquery);
    $stmt->execute($keywords);
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: This answer works, looks like mysql_fetch_assoc() was the problem after all. However, if I may ask, why have you used the three dots before the $keywords in bind_param? Also, how can I skip underscore in the search as whenever I search _ it returns the complete table. The PDO solution works fine as well and much more simple. Thank you for your help again.